# Add/update shapefile to existing PostgreSQL database in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, shp2pgsql

I've an exiting state level PostgreSQL database with some layer's and I need to update an additional data to the existing database.

Ex:

I've a layer called "Road_NW" need to add  additional feature's to this layer and the additional road created with the layer name as "Road_NW".

Comment: your terminology is somewhat unclear; e.g. *shapefiles* have nothing to do with PostgreSQL *per se*, but can be imported as/to a table via the software you mention in the tags. updating features in a PG table is sth. different entirely, but can also be achieved with those software. if you load your layer into QGIS, chances are (depending e.g. on table constraints) you can directly edit it and save changes back to the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'export to Postgres' tool in QGIS. You'll notice there is a tick box at the bottom for 'overwrite' - if you make sure this is ticked your old layer will be updated with the new features.

Answer (score 0):

For future work and to improve on work efficiency, I suggest you link your PostgreSQL database to QGIS desktop, this way, when you do changes to your data in the database it gets updated immediately in the database instead of deleting the table and reimporting it or exporting to Postgres via QGIS.